Electric field just outside and just inside a current carrying conductor
While solving a problem related to electric fields I came across a conclusion in the solution that, for a "straight, steady current carrying conducting wire" having current $I$, so that the charges flow on its surface (obviously because it's a conductor), the electric field just outside the wire $E_{out} \neq 0$ i.e. finite and electric field just inside $E_{in}= 0$. (Note $E_{in}$ does not mean $E$ field at any point inside wire - it's for a point just inside the surface of the wire, same for $ E_{out}.$)
But I think it should be just opposite because just outside the wire or be it far away from wire, when the wire is electrically neutral, it would have $E_{out}=0$. I know that $\vec E$ just outside a conductor is given as $\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$ but that is for the case when the conductor has a net charge. But the wire here should be neutral.
For the second part, considering the wire to be cylindrical, the negative charge that comes to the surface forms a shell, and $E$ field due to the symmetric shell charge is 0. But then the positive immobile ions in the body of wire would exert a net positive $E$ field just inside the wire so $E_{in} \neq 0$.
The Original Problem-
Q.19 A steady current in a straight conducting wire produces a surface charge on it. Let $E_{out}$ and $E_{in }$be the magnitudes of the electric fields just outside and just inside the wire,
respectively. Which of the following statements is true for these fields?
(a) Eout is always greater than Ein
(b) Eout is always smaller than Ein
(c) Eout could be greater or smaller than Ein
(d) Eout is equal to Ein
Solution:
(a)
In this case, $E_{in}=0$, $E_{out} \neq 0$. So $E_{out}$ > $E_{in}$

Your conclusion right at the start is just plain wrong. Ohm's Law has to be obeyed.

Actually its not my conclusion its given in a problem solution,  and i think the ohm's law is obeyed at the surface of wire.

Depends if it's AC/DC current

DC.............. constant current I

Again, that is just wrong. If you want us to look at the problem in greater detail, you will have to post the entire question and its solution, and not as pictures.

@naturallyInconsistent ok i did it, but the solution is very brief, so you maynot find it helpful but its all i have.

The question is not even well-formed. It did not specify if it is considering just the radial component (in which case it is correct) or it is considering the azimuthal component (which is what people are thinking about, which is also the relevant consideration), or the total magnitude. By Faraday's Law, there cannot be a discontinuity in the azimuthal component, and Ohm's Law fixes the DC E field inside the wire to be non-zero.
